# How does defining and immediately calling an anonymous function solve namespace problems?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading [this page](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/tutorials/javascript_best_practices) where it says:

> ```
> myNameSpace = function(){
>   var current = null;
>   function init(){...}
>   function change(){...}
>   function verify(){...}
>   return{
>     init:init,
>     change:change
>   }
> }();
> ```
>
> Instead of returning the properties and methods I just return pointers
>   to them. This makes it easy to call functions and access variables
>   from other places without having to go through the myNameSpace name.

But I don't see how that's true. You still have to do `myNameSpace.init()` to call `init`. `init()` alone doesn't work.

Edit: it occurred to me later that maybe the author meant they were able to call `init()` without qualification *inside the anonymous function*. But what stumped me is that the author's previous examples were already able to do that. Specifically, in the immediately foregoing example:

```
myNameSpace = function(){
  var current = null;
  function verify(){...}
  return{
    init:function(){...}
    change:function(){...}
  }
}();
```

s/he defined `init` as s/he was returning it, instead of the example above where s/he defined init first then returned a pointer to it. But in that earlier example, within the anonymous function, if you wanted to call `init()` without having to do `myNameSpace.init()`, you already can. So how is the quoted example better?.

Can someone explain? Thanks.

Comment: `Calling myNameSpace.set() will now invoke the change() method.` The same page mentioned this in the next paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording is a bit confusing. He meant to say:

> Functions and variables can now be easily accessed without a namespace *from inside* the module

- in contrast to the object literal pattern or the previous example where he put the public methods directly on the exported object. Of course, from outside you *always*  will need to access them as properties of the namespace object - that's the whole point of making it a namespace :-)

For an example, let's fill the functions with a some minimal code:

```
myNameSpace = function(){
  var current = null;
  function verify(…){…}
  return {
    init:function(el){
      el.addEventListener("input", myNameSpace.change, false);
      //                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    },
    change:function(){
      if (!verify(this.value)) alert("wrong");
    }
  }
}();
myNameSpace.init(document.getElementById("testInput"));
```

vs

```
myNameSpace = function(){
  var current = null;
  function verify(…){…}
  function change(){
    if (!verify(this.value)) alert("wrong");
  }
  function init(el){
    el.addEventListener("input", change, false);
    //                           ^^^^^^
  }
  return {
    init:init,
    change:change
  }
}();
myNameSpace.init(document.getElementById("testInput")); // no difference here
```

The differences may be minimal in this example, but when you have lots of functions mutually referencing each other it can matter. Also, you would know that all local, namespace-less functions belong to the current module, which massively increases maintainability when dealing with many different namespaces.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion as you, but what stumped me is that the author's previous examples were already able to do that. Specifically, in the immediately foregoing example, s/he defined `init` as s/he was returning it, instead of the example I quoted where s/he defined `init` first then returned a pointer to it. But in that earlier example, within the anonymous function, if you wanted to call `init()` without having to do `myNameSpace.init()`, you already can. So how is the quoted example better?

Comment: No you cannot omit the namespace in the example where the functions are defined on the exported object literal - try it! See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of using a function to clean up scope is, let's say you have a program that looks like this:

```js
var number = 10;
var multiplier = 2;
var endingText = " days left!";
var string = (10 * 2) + endingText;
// string is "20 days left!"
```

This is an extremely contrived example, but hopefully it's obvious enough that this will declare four variables in the global scope, which is horrible. Let's say what you really want is `string`, but you still want to keep the other three variables around for whatever reason. You can put them inside an anonymous function, like so:

```js
var string;
(function(){
  var number = 10;
  var multiplier = 2;
  var endingText = " days left!";
  string = (10 * 2) + endingText;
})();
// string is still "20 days left!"
```

Because variables are function scoped, `number`, `multiplier` and `endingText` are NOT declared in the global scope. However, you are still able to use them to get the result that you wanted in the first place.

By the way, you need to wrap parens around a function if you want to immediately invoke it. Also, you should not confuse this with namespacing. Namespacing in JavaScript is the idea of assigning meaningful values to the properties of objects.

```js
var foo = {
  hello: "goodbye",
  frank: "bob"
};
```

`hello` and `frank` are declared in the `foo` namespace. That's all there is to it. The example that you posted uses both the namespacing concept and immediately invoking function concept to clean up variables.

Comment: Yours is a nice answer, but unfortunately it doesn't quite address my question. What I really wanted to know is why the author claimed the quoted code "makes it easy to call functions and access variables", while calling `init()` still requires `myNameSpace.init()` just like the author's very first example, which they wanted to avoid.

Comment: Hm. Well, you're right that it doesn't make it any easier to access those functions. The benefit of the code block that you posted is that it manages variables in closure, and stores those two functions in a namespace.